# How to select kendo grid row if that row is not present on first page of the kendo grid./

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Tried to select a kendo grid row in dataBound (Note: that row is not on first page of the grid) but it didn't selected 3rd page row.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
            if (id!== "" && id!== undefined && id!== null) {
                var grid = e.sender;
                grid.select("tr:contains('" + id + "')");
            }
        },
```

Here id is in the page URL and getting ids value like below: and that will get passed in dataBound id var.

```
id = $location.search().id;
```

Any ideas how i can select the 3rd page row? Above logic works for the rows that are present on first page of the kendo grid

When tried selecting 3rd page row, it stays at first page only with nothing selected since that row belongs to third page of the grid.

Comment: You can't. Not that way. The rows(`tr`s) are recreated on page change, so if you're not in page #3 you can't find a `tr` from it. You have to try another  approach, maybe dealing with data directly?

Comment: In other words you read some unique ID value from url fragments and you want to highlight corresponding item from Kendo UI Grid? In this case item with same ID is at third page. Take a look at this link http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/Selection/persist-row-selection-while-paging

Comment: Tried traversing through datasource but on change of page, its calling databound, causing infinite loop. hence no luck.

Comment: `var grid = e.sender;
 var data = grid.dataSource.data();
  var res = $.grep(data, function (d) {
                        return d.Id == id;
                    });var items = grid.items();
                    var itemsToSelect = [];
                    items.each(function (idx, row) {
                        var dataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
                        if (res[0].Id==dataItem.Id) {
                            itemsToSelect.push(row);
                        }
                    });
                    e.sender.select(itemsToSelect);`

Comment: Here grid.items(); results only for the first page.

Comment: However, the row for the third page was selected but it didn't move to the third page automatically

Comment: Had to manually reach to third page and found that the row was selected. The reason was that in 'items', that results for the first page. If i change the page programatically, it causes infinite loop for databound.

Comment: If you want to do the selection just for first dataBound, you can have a flag to understand it. dataBound: function(e) { if(!initialized){ select your item } initialized = true; }

Comment: @uygar Thanks a lot. Finally worked.

Answer (score 1):

Below function is for finding dataItem and selection of any page row.

Var initial prevents the databound to get called after first call.

```
function findDataItem(ragGrid, dataItem) {
        initial = true;
        var ds = ragGrid.dataSource;
        var view = window.kendo.data.Query.process(ds.data(), {
            filter: ds.filter(),
            sort: ds.sort()
        }).data;
        var index = -1;
        for (var x = 0; x < view.length; x++) {
            if (view[x].Id == dataItem.Id) {
                index = x;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (index === -1) {
            return;
        }
        var page = Math.floor(index / ragGrid.dataSource.pageSize());
        var targetIndex = index - (page * ragGrid.dataSource.pageSize())+ 1;
        ragGrid.dataSource.page(++page);
        var row = $("#ragGrid").find("tr:eq(" + targetIndex + ")");
        ragGrid.select(row);
    }
```

Here is the dataBound function and calling findDataItem in dataBound first call.

```
  dataBound: function (e) {
            if (id !== "" && id !== undefined && id !== null) {
                if (!initial){
                var grid = e.sender;
                var data = grid.dataSource.data();
                var res = $.grep(data, function (d) {
                    return d.Id == id;
                });
                findDataItem(grid, res[0]);
                }
            }
        },
```