# Selecting Kendo Ui Grid rows

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to programmatically select certain rows of my Grid using angularJs.

Here is my Code :

```
angular.forEach($scope.Customers, function (rowData) {
    var grid = $(".grid_container").data("kendoGrid");
    var dataItem = $(".grid_container").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.gt(rowData.Id);
    var row = $(".grid_container").data("kendoGrid").tbody.find("tr[data-uid='" + dataItem.uid + "']");
    grid.select(row)
});
```

Now this code select rows which are on 1st page ( one that is visible ). Any other possible way to select those rows which are not on first page.

Note : I have set **PersistSelection** to true. Works fine when i manually select rows.

Comment: i think you can't select item on page 2, from page 1. But you could navigate to the page where the item existed and select it, from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655978/how-to-select-kendo-grid-row-if-that-row-is-not-present-on-first-page-of-the-ken?rq=1

Comment: Yes. But I wanted to set selected row Ids irrespective of the active page and when I visit that particular  page it should show that row as selected. For now I have added a function in data-bound and a variable for storing selected data to achieve this which I feel is not very optimized solution.